# I can't get getRangeStream of the appearance of the pdf when I put the fourth parameter in PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, ...)

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

The following code snippet I use to get the hash of my pdf file.

```
   os = new FileOutputStream(rutaDestinoArchivo);
        PdfStamper stamper;
        if (claveEncriptar != null && !claveEncriptar.isEmpty()) {
            stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(rutaDestinoArchivo + ".tmp"), false);
            stamper.setEncryption(claveEncriptar.getBytes(),
                    claveEncriptar.getBytes(),
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
        } else {
            stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', new File(rutaDestinoArchivo + ".tmp"), true);
        }
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

        if (!seguirFirmando) {
            appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        }

        motivo = " " + motivo + " ";
        if (motivo.length() > 0) {
            String[] parts = motivo.split("@motloc@");
            String part11 = parts[0].trim();
            String part21 = parts[1].trim();
            motivo = "";
            localidad = "";
            if (part11.length() > 0) {
                motivo = part11;
            }
            if (part21.length() > 0) {
                localidad = part21;
            }
        } else {
            motivo = "";
            localidad = "";
        }
        appearance.setReason(motivo);
        appearance.setLocation(localidad);
       
        String ttitulo = tituloFirma;
        if (ttitulo.length() == 0) {
            ttitulo = "FIRMA DIGITAL";
        }
        Integer ttamletra = tamanoLetra;
        if (ttamletra > 0) {
            appearance.setLayer2Font(new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, ttamletra));
        }
        if (descripcion != null && !descripcion.trim().isEmpty()) {
            appearance.setLayer2Text(descripcion);
        }
        appearance.setLayer4Text(ttitulo);
        appearance.setAcro6Layers(true);
        appearance.setImageScale(0.5f);
        appearance.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR);
        if (firmaVisible) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date date = new Date();
            this.nombreFirma = ((nombreFirma != null && !nombreFirma.trim().isEmpty()) ? nombreFirma : "sig" + dateFormat.format(date));
            if (rutaArchivoImagen == null || rutaArchivoImagen.isEmpty()) {
                appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
            } else {
                appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION);
                Image watermark = Image.getInstance(rutaArchivoImagen);
                appearance.setSignatureGraphic(watermark);
            }
            appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(x, y, x + ancho, y + alto), pagina, this.nombreFirma);
        }
        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE,
                PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(appearance, external, tamanoFirma);
        
        InputStream inp = appearance.getRangeStream();
```

I can't longer retrieve the rangeStream() from the appearance, it returns the following exception.

[It returns ioException stream close when I want to get the rangeStream of the appearance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeuxc.png)

When I pass the fourth parameter en la function createSignature as null if I can get the rangeStream() of the appearance.

Naturally I enter the fourth parameter because it allows me to sign large pdf files.

Comment: Please copy & paste the text into your question body instead of linking screen shot excerpts. If you had done so, you probably would have seen that you have provided no exception, let alone stack trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, just edited the question. Regards

Comment: Ok, indeed `MakeSignature.signExternalContainer` may close the underlying streams. You should use an `ExternalSignatureContainer` implementation that already operates on the given data (which is the range stream _before_ closing), e.g. by calculating the hash, instead of `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer`.

Comment: I couldn't solve it, I'll keep trying another time. In the meantime I'll keep passing the temp parameter to null to get the bytes of my pdf file with the appearance added. It's the only solution I found so far. Thanks for the help.